# How to force multithreading on inputs in an SSIS custom Dataflow Component

Tags: ssis

I'm writing an SCD2 lookup component that has 2 inputs:

- The main data flow input, containing business keys and effective dates,
- An input for populating a cache of SCD2 records containing surrogate keys to seek.

I need to effectively pause / retard the first input until all of the buffers in the 2nd input have been consumed and a dictionary has been built.

Problem is that once SSIS sends a buffer on input #1, it never sends any more buffers on the cache input until the main input's buffer has been processed.

How do I effectively put input#1 to sleep while processing input#2?

Answer (score -1):

I'm in the same camp as @lewiguez - I'm not famliar with any of these technologies.  However, it does sound like you want to do this asynchronously so I googled "ssis asynchronous" and I got this promising hit:
[Creating an Asynchronous Transformation with the Script Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx)

Hope this helps you...